# Widgets changing position in Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Whenever I run this program on Emulator, the positions of the widgets change, I tried changing the emulator, size of the layout(Device For Preview), but it wasn't helpful. Please Help me Out.
One solution I got was by decreasing the size of widgets, and arranging widgets to the top of the layout, but it was very time consuming. Also any widget placed at the bottom of the layout wouldn't even show up in the Emulator.

**Layout**
[image]

**Emulator**

[image]

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".button">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="116dp"
                android:background="#D2F0FD"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="10 + 5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scoreBoard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="273dp"
                android:background="#F44336"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="0/0"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:layout_width="183dp"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="487dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="result"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="127dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-417dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="133dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="528dp"
                android:onClick="playAgain"
                android:text="Play Again!"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
                android:background="#FF9800"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="30s"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="182dp"
                app:columnCount="2"
                app:rowCount="2">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#2196F3"
                    android:onClick="chosAns"
                    android:tag="1"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_gravity="fill"
                    app:layout_row="0"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#E80909"
                    android:onClick="chosAns"
                    android:tag="2"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    app:layout_column="1"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_gravity="fill"
                    app:layout_row="0"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#62F806"
                    android:onClick="chosAns"
                    android:tag="3"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_gravity="fill"
                    app:layout_row="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#8448E4"
                    android:onClick="chosAns"
                    android:tag="4"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    app:layout_column="1"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_gravity="fill"
                    app:layout_row="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1" />
            </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/go"
                android:layout_width="268dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="433dp"
                android:background="#3FED46"
                android:onClick="hideIt"
                android:text="GO!!"
                android:textSize="60dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your first mistake is using a `RelativeLayout` (actually two!) inside of a `ConstraintLayout`. That's pointless. Use just the `ConstraintLayout`, as it's basically a superior `RelativeLayout`. And you're trying to use `ConstraintLayout` constraints in `Views` that aren't direct children of the `ConstraintLayout`. This will have no effect.

Comment: Basically I was just following a Tutorial, and the guy in that tutorial did the same. That last Button 'go' isn't part of the child relative layout. It just went inside that child relative layout while I was moving that button

Answer (score 0):

Because you are nesting Constraint Layout with Relative Layout which contains widget that may lead to overflowing.